# Component state not getting updated after axios request is resolved

Tags: reactjs, axios, state

Here is my code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import PlanDetails from "./PlanDetails";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import PropTypes from "prop-types"; //ES6

class Planner extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      destinations: [],
      vacations: [],
      itineraries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    axios
      .get("sample.json")
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        self.setState(data => {
          destinations: data.destinations;
          vacations: data.vacations;
          itineraries: data.itineraries;
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Planner</h1>
        <PlanDetails />
        <Pagination />

        <ul>
          {this.state.destinations.map(destination => (
            <li key={destination.url}>{destination.text}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Planner.propTypes = {};

export default Planner;
```

In the above example I am trying to get the value from local JSON with the help of axios and I want to update the response in my state of the planner component. It is not reflecting.

Is there any new ways to implement this? I am new to react.

Comment: Are you new to javascript altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` syntax is incorrect in your code. Also you don't need `self` since you are using arrow function for axios `.then` callback which will bind the context to the enclosing scope

```
  this.setState({
      destinations: data.destinations,
      vacations: data.vacations,
      itineraries: data.itineraries
    });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should use comma `,` instead  semi-colon `;` inside the `setState()` :)